# Angular ui-router-extras $$uirouterextrasreload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular-ui-router-extras

When I reload my ui-router's state like this:

```
$state.go('login', null, {reload: true});
```

I get a url parameter **$$uirouterextrasreload**

```
http://localhost:3000/#/login?$$uirouterextrasreload=0.40401903772726655
```

Does anybody know why is this parameter adds to url and how to remove this parameter?

Comment: Interesting.  Looks like a bug.  Would you mind filing a bug and include a small plnkr.co example that reproduces this?

Comment: https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/181